# getting new value of input field on keypressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an input field where i allow users to insert an integer.

Now when ever they insert a value into the input field i check with ajax if it is higher than a specefic amount for this purpose i need to get the  "new" value of the input field

i have tried the following:

```
    $('.wanted_amount').keydown(function () {
        var  value =   $(this).val();
}
```

however this returns  `""`

Meaning that it doesnt register the value untill after keydown

So how i can i get the new value of the input field with javascript?

Comment: Use the other key events? `keypress`/`keyup`

Comment: Check this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/6ey7P/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you please try this,

```
 $(function(){
    $('.wanted_amount').keyup(function () {
       var  value =   $(this).val(); // alert(value);
    }); 
 });



keydown is event, which helps to trigger event when detects a finger on a key 

keyup is event, which helps to trigger event when the key is released
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not closed function properly.

`keydown()` will be triggered when key is pressed and `keyup()` will be triggered after pressing the key. In your case, `keyup()` is more suitable.

Try this:

```
$('.wanted_amount').keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/KkbpJ/)